# Animate background of submit button on press?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to animate a button on submit.

I have the following html:

```
<input id="save" val="save" />
```

and css:

```
#save { background: #ccc; }

.saving { background: #ccc url(/img/savingstripes.png) repeat; }
```

and jquery:

```
$('#save').click(function(e) { 

  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).addClass('saving').animate({backgroundPosition: '100px 0px'});

})
```

When I press this button, all I get is the class 'saving' added to the button but no animation.

What am I missing in this? (Note: I have the [backgroundPosition plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect))

Comment: @joseph: Surely you shouldn't be correcting his code in the question.

Comment: @tw16 don't see why not.  He says it adds the saving class so obviously those typos are not the issue

Comment: yeah, sorry that was a typo as I've just retyped the shortened relevant code in the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what happened... it's your `background: #ccc;` declaration.  For some reason it needs to be `background-color: #ccc;` and won't work any other way.  [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/rk6kj/2/).

Comment: CSS in "ID" #savin will override CSS in "Class" .savin, hence no background image. So if you were to set background color different in both, you will see that the Class color will never come through. which you can see here, i removed/broke link to image. http://jsfiddle.net/rk6kj/3/ So, in short, setting "background" in id will ride any sub categories of property "background-" in class.

Answer (score 2):

```
#save { background: #ccc; }
```

This CSS is overwriting your background image

Use

```
#save { background-color: #ccc; }
```

Comment: That's it... now I remember.  id styles take precedence over class styles.  They don't cascade as they should.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add some weight to your `.saving` CSS class by including the input's id:

```
#save.saving { background: #ccc url(/img/savingstripes.png) repeat; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5Q5N/